# How to get actual image to post?

Tags: support, images

I have a question about my Super User post: [How to get rid of white edges](https://superuser.com/questions/1348423/how-to-get-rid-of-white-edges)

When I first posted this question, the appended image didn't show up.  Instead, there was just the word "graphics," highlighted.  Tetsujin kindly fixed it for me.  How do I get the image to show up instead of the highlighted word?

Answer (score 5):

The word [graphics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics) on your question there is a [tag](https://superuser.com/help/tagging). Every question must have at least one tag. For example, this question here has two, [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [images](/questions/tagged/images).

Where you meant for there to be an image, there was the word "transparent" as a link to the image. To prevent abuse, new users [are not allowed to embed images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/295684) on a handful of large Stack Exchange sites including Super User. You will be to include embedded images once you reach 10 reputation. After that, the image insertion feature of the post editor will produce an embedded image, or you'll be able to use the syntax shown at the bottom of [the formatting help page](https://superuser.com/help/formatting).